# How to group results after a selection in Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a controller that returns me `expiration_date` and `status` of a ticket, referring an `user_id`.

After I get all tickets that an user has registered, the controller will show when expire and the status. Something like this:

```
0   
expiration_date "2018-03-03 20:38:32"
status  "expired"

1   
expiration_date "2018-03-03 20:38:32"
status  "expired"

2   
expiration_date "2018-03-03 20:38:32"
status  "expired"

3
expiration_date "2018-05-03 09:02:06"
status  "expired"

4
expiration_date "2019-05-03 09:02:06"
status  "available"

5   
expiration_date "2019-05-03 10:00:20"
status  "available"
```

My problem here is that I need to group the data that has the same `expiration_date` and `status`. So, I would group the data 0, 1, 2 and the data 4 and 5 in an unique item, counting the number of items. Something like this:

```
Count: 3
expiration_date "2018-03-03 20:38:32"
status  "expired"

Count: 1
expiration_date "2018-05-03 09:02:06"
status  "expired"

Count: 2
expiration_date "2019-05-03 10:00:20"
status  "available"
```

So, how do I do that? I'm using Laravel with mysql and here it is my Controller.

**ControllerPHP**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use DB;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class UsersCreditsController extends Controller 
{

    public function getTicketsStatusByUserId($userId)
    {   

        $users = DB::select("
            SELECT COUNT(user_id)
             FROM users_credits 
             WHERE user_id = $userId
        ");

        foreach ($users as $user) {
          $item = DB::select("
              SELECT expiration_date, status
              FROM users_credits 
              WHERE user_id = $userId
              ORDER BY expiration_date ASC
          ");
          return $item;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you still concatenate your SQL statements? Use prepared statements and don't even think about concatenating it ever again.

Comment: `GROUP BY expiration_date, status`  before the `ORDER BY` clause and include `COUNT(user_id)` in the result set.

Comment: Since this is Laravel why are you smashing around with raw queries? This kind of operation is supported natively by Eloquent and that approach avoids the huge [SQL injection](http://bobby-tables.com/) problem you have here.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the heads up, guys.
I'll look into this later, but for now thanks @danblack, the problem was solved. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I remade my code using the eloquent that was indicated to me.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use DB;
use App\Http\Requests;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class UsersCreditsController extends Controller 
{
    public function getTicketsStatusByUserId($userId)
    {   
        $item = DB::table('users_credits')
                    ->select('expiration_date as Vencimento', 'status as Status', DB::raw('count(*) as Quantidade'))
                    ->where(function ($query) use ($userId)
                    {
                        $query->where('user_id', '=', $userId);
                        $query->whereNotIn('status', ['used']);
                    })
                    ->groupBy('expiration_date', 'status')
                    ->get();
        return $item;
    }
}
```

The code is working as intended, if anyone need to learn how to use this.

Answer (score 1):

try using eloquent like this;

```
$users=yourtable::where('user_id',$userId)->where('status','expired')->get();
```